# How to design a multithreaded elevator system and handle concurrency?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x

I want to write a multithreaded program for an elevator system.
The elevator system can only move if the state is `running` or `wait` state. 
In the system, the instruction (which floor to go to) can be added in a multithreaded way. For managing the queue of instruction and getting the next stop for the lift, I have written a QueueManager class.
I am not able to figure out how to implement the QueueManager. The problem is I can't get my head around writing the QueueManager. Especially in figuring out how to get the next stop for the Lift from the queue.
Here's my implementation for the system in python3:

```
"""Implementation of a lift System"""

from enum import Enum
from typing import TypeVar
from threading import Thread
import queue


LiftType = TypeVar('LiftType', bound='Lift')
QueueManagerType = TypeVar('QueueManagerType', bound='QueueManager')
SensorNameType = TypeVar('SensorNameType', bound='SensorName')
DirectionType = TypeVar('DirectionType', bound='DirectionType')

class SensorName(Enum):
  weight = 'weight'
  smoke = 'smoke'

class Direction(Enum):
  up = 1
  down = -1

class State(Enum):
  running = 'running'
  wait = 'waiting'
  stop = 'stop'

class Lift:
  def __init__(self, num_floors: int, queue_manager: QueueManagerType):
    """
    Contains all the properties of lift
    """
    self.num_floors = num_floors
    self.curr_direction = Direction.up
    self.state = State.running
    self.curr_floor = 0
    self.queue_manager = queue_manager

  def move(self):
    """
    Moves the lift according to the instruction
    """
    if self.state in [State.running, State.wait]:
      if self.queue_manager.has_instruction():
        self.state = State.running
        stop = self.queue_manager.next_stop(self.curr_direction, self.curr_floor)
        if stop:
          print(stop)
        else:
          if self.curr_direction == Direction.up:
            self.curr_direction = Direction.down
            stop = self.queue_manager.next_stop(self.curr_direction,
                                                self.curr_floor)
            print(stop)
          else:
            self.curr_direction = Direction.up
      else:
        self.state = State.wait

  def add_instruction(self, floor, direction=None):
    """Adds the instruction to the queue"""
    if direction is None:
      if self.curr_floor > floor:
        direction = Direction.down
      else:
        direction = Direction.up
    Thread(target=self.queue_manager.add_instruction, args=(floor, direction)).start()
    self.move()

class QueueManager:
  def __init__(self):
    self.instruction_queue = queue.Queue()

  def add_instruction(self, floor: int, direction: DirectionType):
    """Add an instruction to the queue. Direction is used """
    self.instruction_queue.put([floor, direction])

  def next_stop(self, direction: int, curr_floor: int):
    """Tells which is the next stop based on the direction provided."""
    pass


  def has_instruction(self):
    """If there are any instructions for the lift"""
    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
  # weight_sensor = WeightSensor(SensorName.weight)
  instruction_queue = QueueManager()
  lift_1 = Lift(21, instruction_queue)
  lift_1.add_instruction(floor=0, direction=Direction.up)
  lift_1.add_instruction(floor=2)
```

Extension to the above program is writing a Sensor class which runs in background and sets lift to stop state if certain sensor is triggered. Which is also something I am unable to figure out.

Comment: I'm not sure what your `QueueManager` is intended to do, which makes it hard to tell you how to fix it. A queue, by definition, only lets you peek/pop the head. So how are you expecting to find the next thing for a given direction when the only thing you can ever do is find the next thing full stop? There are data structures that allow you to work from both ends (like a deque) or from anywhere (like a list, or a tree), or you might want two separate queues, or… lots of things that could conceivably be used in this problem, but I can't see how any of them is related to the way you're trying.

Comment: Not able to figure out _how_ to implement the queue manager? or having trouble deciding what you want it to _do_?  I don't believe that a queue is the right data type. I think what you really want is a _set_ of integer values (requested stops), and a method that searches the set for the least stop number that is greater than the current floor number (next stop on the way up), and a method that searches for the greatest stop number that is less than the current floor number (next stop on the way down.)

Comment: P.S., Your question title may be a turn-off for some of the folk who lurk here.  When I clicked on it, I thought I was going to vote to close, because it looked like one of those "questions" where somebody pastes the entire text of their homework assignment, and then expects somebody else to do the work for them.

Comment: @jameslarge: If I use set the concurrent updation of the set through threads would be a problem right?

Comment: @jameslarge: Maybe it does look like one of those questions. But I don't have anyone else to discuss this problem with and understand the flaws in my code. This is the only platform I have.

Comment: @jameslarge - updating any data type in a multithreading setting is quite easily manageable through thread locks (e.g. [`threading.Lock()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Lock), [`threading.RLock()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.RLock)).

Comment: Re,"concurrent update..." Potentially, yes.  You might want to lock a mutex while modifying the set, and lock the same mutex while searching it.

Comment: Re, "one of those questions..."  I was just talking about the title.

Comment: @abarnert: If I ditch QueueManager. What data structure can I use to get the next stop?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what the `QueueManager` is supposed to be doing, so I can't really explain what to do instead. The only obvious design I can think of around `Queue` is to have four priority queues (upward vs. downward, and floors still ahead vs. to catch next time), and that's definitely not the simplest way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the feedback I got in the comments. Here's a multithreaded solution for an elevator system.

```
"""Implementation of a lift System"""

from enum import Enum
from typing import TypeVar
from threading import Lock, Thread
from heapq import heappush, heappop
import time
import random


LiftType = TypeVar('LiftType', bound='Lift')
QueueManagerType = TypeVar('QueueManagerType', bound='QueueManager')
SensorNameType = TypeVar('SensorNameType', bound='SensorName')
DirectionType = TypeVar('DirectionType', bound='DirectionType')

class SensorName(Enum):
  weight = 'weight'
  smoke = 'smoke'

class Direction(Enum):
  up = 1
  down = -1

class State(Enum):
  running = 'running'
  wait = 'waiting'
  stop = 'stop'

class Lift:
  def __init__(self, num_floors: int):
    """
    Contains all the properties of lift
    :param sensors: A list of sensor objects
    """
    self.num_floors = num_floors
    self.curr_direction = Direction.up
    self.state = State.running
    self.curr_floor = 0
    self.instruction_queue = {Direction.up: [], Direction.down: []}
    self.queue_lock = Lock()

  def move(self):
    """
    Moves the lift according to the instruction
    """
    if self.state in [State.running, State.wait]:
      if len(self.instruction_queue[Direction.up]) or len(self.instruction_queue[Direction.down]):
        self.state = State.running
        try:
          stop = heappop(self.instruction_queue[Direction.up])
        except IndexError:
          stop = -1
        if stop > -1:
          self.curr_floor = stop
          print(stop, Direction.up)
        else:
          if self.curr_direction == Direction.up:
            self.curr_direction = Direction.down
            if len(self.instruction_queue[Direction.down]):
              stop = heappop(self.instruction_queue[Direction.down])
              self.curr_floor = stop
              print(stop, Direction.down)
            else:
              self.state = State.wait
          else:
            self.curr_direction = Direction.up
        self.move()
      else:
        self.state = State.wait

  def add_instruction(self, floor, direction=None):
    if direction == Direction.up:
      time.sleep(random.uniform(0,1))
    else:
      time.sleep(random.uniform(0,4))
    if direction is None:
      if self.curr_floor > floor:
        direction = Direction.down
      else:
        direction = Direction.up
    with self.queue_lock:
      heappush(self.instruction_queue[direction], floor)
    self.move()


if __name__ == '__main__':
  lift_1 = Lift(21)
  lift_1.add_instruction(0, Direction.up)
  Thread(target=lift_1.add_instruction, args=(2,)).start()
  Thread(target=lift_1.add_instruction, args=(5,)).start()
  Thread(target=lift_1.add_instruction, args=(2,)).start()
  Thread(target=lift_1.add_instruction, args=(18,)).start()
  Thread(target=lift_1.add_instruction, args=(12,)).start()
  Thread(target=lift_1.add_instruction, args=(21,)).start()
```